# alert onchange of the page title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, page-title

Tried searching a lot.
could not find any solutions for onchange of page title.

There is jQuery `.change()` but that is limited to "input elements, textarea boxes and select elements."

What I am trying is to give an alert whenever any script changes the title of the page.

I am building a Chrome extension that alerts the user when the `document.title` has changed.

Comment: what you have tried? Please provide html and jquery

Comment: Create a fiddle of what you have tried.

Comment: and please tell us what exactly the title that you're referring? whether it is `<title></title>` tag.

Comment: you are looking for mutation observer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: I Can try only when i know what function to use.
@Ravimallya - When I say **PAGE TITLE** it means `<title></title>` and not the `title=""` attribute of an element. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a plugin, I suppose:

```
$.fn.titleChange = function(origTitle,callback){      
   setInterval(function(){
     if(origTitle == document.title){
        return false;
     }
     else {
       callback();
       origTitle = document.title;
     }
   },1000);
}
```

Use the above like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).titleChange(document.title,function(){alert("changed");});
});
```

Comment: this is also the same case as mine....

Comment: As the OP is not clearing describing the problem, we go rambling...

Comment: @C-link, no. It isn't now ;)